# Drawable from mdpi loading instead of hdpi

Tags: android, background, drawable

I have set up my project with different drawable directories (ldpi, mdpi and hdpi). I have a background png with two different resolutions: 320x480 in drawable-mdpi folder, and 480x800 in drawable-hdpi. Both have the same filename. When I try to load the background as a style in the manifest (using android:windowBackground in the style) if I use the emulator for a 1.6 device, I get the correct one loaded(mdpi). However, if I try this on my Nexus, I see that at first the correct background from the hdpi folder is loaded, but it quickly switches to the mdpi one. I have tried also to set up the background in the layout xml file (android:src=...) but in this case only the mdpi one is loaded. If I delete the mdpi version, everything is loaded ok. Any idea on what is the problem? why is it loading the mdpi drawable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In manifest file:

```
  <supports-screens
      android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Hope this hepls

Comment: hmmm I don't know if it was this or something else but now it's working. Thanks!