# Button image lose quality. drawable (hdpi etc. ) catalogues don't help

Tags: android, user-interface, button, background

I set button like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tab_dash"
    android:onClick="tab_dash_click"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_tab_user_default"/>
```

And on my Galaxy S graphic loses quality and I can see ugly pixels no matter what.

I tried everything. The only way it's ok when I put @android:drawable/file_from_sdk

Please help!

Comment: Where is the graphic ic_tab_user_default coming from? If its from the SDK, Have you tried to open the file in a graphic editor to see the actual dimensions? If its not from the SDK, you generally need to make it bigger using vectors if you are experiencing loss.

Comment: Is ic_tab_user_default a 9patch image?

Comment: I got an answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737530/drawable-from-mdpi-loading-instead-of-hdpi

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to make a button with an image. If so, I would recommend using an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html). Or if you want to incorporate text with this button, I would suggest using this XML tag `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_tab_user_default"`. You can replace the `drawableLeft` with `drawableRight`, `drawableBottom`, or `drawableTop`. This generally works pretty well for making a button with text and an icon.

From my experience, using the `background` tag never makes a good quality image for buttons in particular.